# backbone view trigger not working but jquery trigger does

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm working on making a bootstrap modal view with child views for the header, body, and footer. In this the modal view is the parent with the other views as children that are created in the main modal view. The problem I'm having currently is getting events from the child views, in this case the footer buttons, to trigger on the parent modal view. When I use an of the below jQuery selectors and trigger this works, however calling the global Backbone trigger or this.trigger does not and I'm not sure why. The relevant trigger calls are in the close method of the BaseModalFooterView.

EDIT: Here's a working example in JS Bin of it using the jQuery trigger. http://jsbin.com/horasi/1/

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    Playground.Views.BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function (options) {
            this.options = _.defaults(options || {}, this.options);
            this.el = this.options.el || this.el;
        },
        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.options));
            return this;
        }
    });
})();

(function () {
    'use strict';

    Playground.Views.BaseModalHeaderView = Playground.Views.BaseView.extend({
        el: '.modal-header',
        template: JST['app/scripts/templates/BaseModal/BaseModalHeaderView.hbs'],
        options: {
            closeButton: false,
            title: 'Header'
        }
    });

    Playground.Views.BaseModalBodyView = Playground.Views.BaseView.extend({
        el: '.modal-body',
        template: JST['app/scripts/templates/BaseModal/BaseModalBodyView.hbs']
    });

    Playground.Views.BaseModalFooterView = Playground.Views.BaseView.extend({
        el: '.modal-footer',
        template: JST['app/scripts/templates/BaseModal/BaseModalFooterView.hbs'],
        events: {
            'click #close': 'close',
            'click #save': 'save'
        },
        close: function () {
            console.log('close');

            // These work to trigger the event
            $('#base-modal-view').trigger('modal-close');
            // $('body.modal-open').trigger('modal-close');
            // $('body').trigger('modal-close');

            // These do not work
            // Backbone.trigger('modal-close');
            // this.trigger('modal-close');
        },
        save: function () {
            console.log('save');
        }
    });

    Playground.Views.BaseModalView = Playground.Views.BaseView.extend({
        el: 'body',
        id: 'base-modal-view',
        template: JST['app/scripts/templates/BaseModal/BaseModalView.hbs'],
        options: {
            views: {
                header: Playground.Views.BaseModalHeaderView,
                body: Playground.Views.BaseModalBodyView,
                footer: Playground.Views.BaseModalFooterView
            }
        },
        events: {
            'modal-close': 'hide'
        },
        initialize: function (options) {
            Playground.Views.BaseView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, options);
            if (this.model) {
                this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
            }
        },
        render: function () {
            this.$el.append(this.template({
                id: this.id,
                model: ((this.model) ? this.model.toJSON() : {})
            }));
            this.renderSection('header')
                .renderSection('body')
                .renderSection('footer');
            return this;
        },
        renderSection: function (section) {
            var view = new this.options.views[section](this.options[section] || {});
            view.render();
            return this;
        },
        show: function () {
            this.$('#' + this.id).modal('show');
        },
        hide: function (e, data) {
            console.log('hide', data);
            this.$('#' + this.id).modal('hide');
        }
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use your own event dispatcher extending [`Backbone.Events`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events).

**From backbone documentation:** *For example, to make a handy event dispatcher that can coordinate events among different areas of your application.*

Example:

```
var ModalEventDispatcher = {};

_.extend(ModalEventDispatcher, Backbone.Events);

// Somewhere in your base BaseModalView

ModalEventDispatcher.on('model:save', yourCallbackfunction);

// Somewhere in BaseModalFooterView

ModalEventDispatcher.trigger('modal:save', options);
```

This example demonstrates basic approach which easily could solve your issue.

Comment: I've changed the way I'm handling things now so I don't have a need yet for the event dispatcher but I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cant use events for backbone events , you have to use instead of :

```
events: {
            'modal-close': 'hide'
        },
```

on initialize of the view

```
this.listenTo(view, "modal-close", this.hide);
```

Comment: I've since gone an different way with this but I think you're correct. Looking at the event hash it makes use of jQuery's .on() method to attach DOM events. Thanks